# Finding specific field in API method using Postman and Javascript

Tags: javascript, postman

This is probably a very basic question but I'm struggling to find helpful resources. I have a controller in an API which returns:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
   "ID": 1062,
   "Code": "MITCHARD001",
   "Surname": "Mitchard",
   "FirstNames": "Alexander John",
   "PreferredName": "Alex",
   "Title": "Dr",
   "Initials": "A J",
   "Suffix": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

My tests need to check if the API is responding with the expected data for each of the fields.

I can't find any documentation for searching responseBody at this level, tough I really found some useful functions(E.g **.has**).

All the examples I've found work around an array with multiple values for a single field name.

I'm a beginner at javascript and probably, I'm not googling the correct terminology.

Could someone show me how I can easily search through each field of my JSON?

P.S. Also, would be nice if any of you could demonstrate other functions beyond **.has** already metioned.

Comment: `responseBody.value[0].ID` should give you `1062` - does it not? Also, please include the relevant parts of the code that you currently are using.

Comment: Is this something an assertion library can help with? ie checking deep equality using chai: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Comment: Tomalak, this doesn't seem to work.  I've tried:

    tests["ID 1062 found"] = responseBody.value[0].ID === 1062;

But am getting "There was an error evaluating the test script. Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Calvin, I'm not familiar with assertion libraries and chai (normally test websites using selenium and c# so this is uncharted territory for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the response body to `JSON`.

```
var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["ID 1062 found"] = responseJson.value[0].ID === 1062;
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work but I'm getting  "There was an error evaluating the test script. Cannot read property '0' of undefined".  I'm assuming others are not having similar problems with the free version of the Postman app so am starting to come to the conclusion that although the prototype API I'm working with appears to be working (the output in the Body area of Postman looks correct) there is a dev problem.

Comment: Spotted the flaw!  the tests line should be looking at responseJson not responseBody.  Many thanks - that's giving what I need :)

Comment: @Chrissi oops, my bad. Fixing this